# Crossing string lists in Tensorflow tf.feature_column.crossed_column

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have two features `post_tags` and `user_tags`. These are padded strings of N and M words respectivley.

So for example we might have `post_tag` being `"the-oscars brad-pitt xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz"`. So this post has been tagged as oscars and brad pitt related.

Then for a `user_tag` we might have `"brad-pitt universal sag the-academy-awards xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz"`

`user_tag` here is a sample of tags from last 20 posts user last consumed say.

So `post_tag` is always 5 tags long and `user_tag` is always 10 tags long.

I'm splitting each string into a tensor as part of dataset api processing like this:

```
features['post_tag'] = tf.string_split([features['post_tag']])
features['post_tag'] = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(features['post_tag'], default_value=PADWORD)
features['user_tag'] = tf.string_split([features['post_tag']])
features['user_tag'] = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(features['post_tag'], default_value=PADWORD)
```

I have a vocab file for the tags and am feeding each feature into the deep features of a wide and deep canned estimator.

```
user_tag = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(
            key='user_tag',
            vocabulary_file='{}/tagvocab.csv'.format(INPUT_DIR)
            )
user_tag_embed = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
        categorical_column = user_tag ,
        dimension = USER_TAG_EMBEDDING_SIZE
        )
deep.append(user_tag_embed)

post_tag = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(
                key='post_tag',
                vocabulary_file='{}/tagvocab.csv'.format(INPUT_DIR)
                )
    post_tag _embed = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
            categorical_column = post_tag ,
            dimension = POST_TAG_EMBEDDING_SIZE
            )
    deep.append(post_tag_embed)
```

This works however what i really want to do is to do a cross of `post_tag` and `user_tag`. But if i do something like this:

```
user_post_tag_cross = tf.feature_column.crossed_column(
        keys = [user_tag, post_tag],
        hash_bucket_size = 25
        )
wide.append(user_post_tag_cross)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected D2 of index to be 2 got 3 at position 0
```

I can see this is coming from [this line in the tf code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3bc595df1d9ea2015fa892bbd69c38ae4c4857d3/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_cross_op.cc#L366)

I have a feeling maybe crossing tensors like this might not be possible or it expecting just two strings. I have related features that are `post_tag_first` and `user_tag_first` which are just one random tag and just being passed in as strings. Then if i do:

```
user_post_first_tag_cross = tf.feature_column.crossed_column(
            keys = ['user_tag_first', 'post_tag_first'],
            hash_bucket_size = 25
            )
wide.append(user_post_first_tag_cross)
```

It works and trains fine. So really i'm just trying to understand what the best way would be to do a cross of two tensors of tags.

Anyone any ideas - i'd imagine it's something someone might have dealt with before as sort of tag data like this is pretty common, or it could be search terms and document terms, keywords, etc.

### Update - small reproducible example

Here is a small runable example that sets up what i'm looking to do.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# set up tag vocab
tag_vocab = ['brad-pitt','usa','donald-trump','tpb','tensorflow','xyzpadxyz','UNK']

# make data

# train data
user_tag_train = np.random.choice(tag_vocab,50).reshape((5, 10)) # 5 example rows with 10 tags per user
post_tag_train = np.random.choice(tag_vocab,25).reshape((5, 5)) # 5 example rows with 5 tags per post
x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]) # just another example numeric feature
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3., -4]) # outcome

# eval data
user_tag_eval = np.random.choice(tag_vocab,50).reshape((5, 10)) # 5 example rows with 10 tags per user
post_tag_eval = np.random.choice(tag_vocab,25).reshape((5, 5)) # 5 example rows with 5 tags per post
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1., 5.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0., 9.])

# define feature cols

x_num = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[1])

user_tag_cat = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key = 'user_tag',
    vocabulary_list = tag_vocab)

user_tag_embed = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
    categorical_column = user_tag_cat,
    dimension = 3
)

post_tag_cat = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key = 'post_tag',
    vocabulary_list = tag_vocab)

post_tag_embed = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
    categorical_column = post_tag_cat,
    dimension = 2
)

user_post_tag_cross = tf.feature_column.crossed_column(
    keys = [ user_tag_cat, post_tag_cat ],
    hash_bucket_size = 5
)

#user_post_tag_embed_cross = tf.feature_column.crossed_column(
#    keys = [ user_tag_embed, post_tag_embed ],
#    hash_bucket_size = 5
#)

feature_columns = [
  x_num,
  user_tag_cat,
  post_tag_cat,
  user_tag_embed,
  post_tag_embed,
  user_post_tag_cross,
  #user_post_tag_embed_cross,
  ]

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {
      "x": x_train,
      "user_tag": user_tag_train,
      "post_tag": post_tag_train,
    }, 
    y_train, 
    batch_size=5, 
    num_epochs=None, 
    shuffle=True
    )

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {
      "x": x_train,
      "user_tag": user_tag_train,
      "post_tag": post_tag_train,
      }, 
    y_train, 
    batch_size=5, 
    num_epochs=1000, 
    shuffle=False
    )

eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {
      "x": x_eval,
      "user_tag": user_tag_eval,
      "post_tag": post_tag_eval
      }, 
    y_eval, 
    batch_size=5, 
    num_epochs=1000, 
    shuffle=False
    )

estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_fn)

eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

print("\n\ntrain metrics: %r"% train_metrics)
print("eval metrics: %r"% eval_metrics)
```

The above code runs, but if you uncomment the parts relating to `user_post_tag_embed_cross` you get (as expected):

```
ValueError: Unsupported key type. All keys must be either string, or categorical column except _HashedCategoricalColumn. Given: _EmbeddingColumn(categorical_column=_VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='user_tag', vocabulary_list=('brad-pitt', 'usa', 'donald-trump', 'tpb', 'tensorflow', 'xyzpadxyz', 'UNK'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0), dimension=3, combiner='mean', initializer=<tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops.TruncatedNormal object at 0x0000021C9AA14860>, ckpt_to_load_from=None, tensor_name_in_ckpt=None, max_norm=None, trainable=True)
```

In reality i don't think i'd be able to do `user_post_tag_cross` as the tag vocab is ~40k (i was surprised it worked here as i think this is what led to the error i linked to above - maybe its related to when you try cross two cats with big vocab's).

I think ideally what i'd want to do is just cross the embeddings in some way. If i put both into a embedding with same dimension then is there a way to cross that somehow using feature_columns() or some other approach?

Comment: When defining the feature cross, are you wanting to maintain the order of the tags within each sublist? Or can these be treated as a "bag of tags"? Assuming it is "bag of tags", let me verify the semantics. Given  user_tags = ["a", "c", "f"] and post_tags=["m", "o"], you want a binary features "user_tag=a&post_tag=m", "user_tag=a&post_tag=o", "user_tag=c&post_tag=m", ... "user_tag=f&post_tag=o" Is that correct?

Comment: bag of tags is indeed the approach i'm going for. So binary features like you mention. I guess though if i'm not careful that could get insanely wide - i have ~40k tags in the vocab. Or is there a way that tf can efficiently represent that - maybe hash bucket the crosses or something.

Comment: embedding and/or hash bucket of crosses would do. I personally don't know how to do this using feature columns, but I'm trying to find people that do.

Comment: We recommend the second approach because it skips the integerization of individual features and does the cross directly on the strings. Having said that both approach should work. Could you please create a small script which reproduces the error.

Comment: i tired to just do a cross of the embeddings but crossed_column only takes categorical i think. Any idea how i might go about doing a cross of the embeddings. I'll try do a small reproducible example tomorrow. In meantime if you've any ideas i can try as well in morning id live to hear them. Or even how i might cross two _HashedCategoricalColumn in a much lower dimensional space?

Comment: @user1454804 i just added a runable example , does it help make it clearer what i'm trying to do?